# How to sort a composite struct with string and number?

Tags: rust

So  this is my struct. As you can see it's a composite struct (string and number/Decimal)

```
use rust_decimal::prelude::*;

#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize, Clone, Eq, Ord, PartialEq, PartialOrd)]
pub struct Row {
    pub acc_code: String,
    pub acc_type: String,
    pub acc_name: String,
    pub before: Decimal,
    pub total: Decimal,
    pub after: Decimal,
}
```

and this is how I sort an array (Vector) of this struct. I use the `sort_by_key()` method for vector:

```
   let sort_by = Some("acc_code");
   let container: Vec<Row> = vec![];

    // sorting
    match view_options.sort_by {
        Some(sort_by) => {
            container.sort_by_key(|r| match sort_by.as_ref() {
                "acc_code" => r.acc_code.clone(),
                "acc_type" => r.acc_type.clone(),
                "acc_name" => r.acc_name.clone(),
                "before" => r.before.to_string(), // this is  the source of the problem
                "after" => r.after.to_string(), // I can only use one of the type
                "total" => r.total.to_string(), // either string or number here
                _ => r.acc_code.clone(),
            });
        }
        None => {}
    }
```

this works as long as it only sort field with string type (`acc_code`, `acc_type` or `acc_name`).

If you sort the number field (like `total`, `after` or `before`), it only sort the first character of that number (since it is converted to a string), eg: `[1000, 4, 500, 6]`. Rust only sees the first character of that number and doesn't consider the rest

I had to use string for sort_by_key to work since it requires unified output types. So either I convert the number into string or convert the string into number. So how do I give a numerical "value" into a string so it will sort properly across any field ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `sort_by_key()`, use [`sort_by()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.sort_by):

```rust
container.sort_by(|a, b| match sort_by.as_ref() {
    "acc_code" => a.acc_code.cmp(&b.acc_code),
    "acc_type" => a.acc_type.cmp(&b.acc_type),
    "acc_name" => a.acc_name.cmp(&b.acc_name),
    "before" => a.before.cmp(&b.before),
    "after" => a.after.cmp(&b.after),
    "total" => a.kredit.cmp(&b.kredit),
    _ => a.acc_code.cmp(&b.acc_code),
});
```

Comment: ah... I see to the `cmp()` is like `localeCompare()` in Javascript.

Comment: Note that performance-wise, it might be better to swap the closure and the `match`, e.g. `container.sort_by ({ match sort_by.as_ref() { "acc_code" => |a: &Row, b: &Row| a.acc_code.cmp (&b.acc_code), … }})` (benchmark to make sure).

Comment: @Jmb Not necessarily, because it'll incur a dynamic call.

Comment: The compiler may be able to optimize the dynamic call, but even if it doesn't a dynamic call should be faster than a string comparison (especially once the branch predictor kicks in). Anyway that's why I said to benchmark.